# Does shiva support c++11 standard?

Tags: shiva3d

Does `Shiva` support the `C++11` standard?
I want to learn how to use a game engine and I already know `C++`, so I prefer `Shiva` over `Unity` if it supports `C++11`.

Answer (score 0):

`ShiVa` engine development does support development `C++`.

Please see [here](http://www.stonetrip.com/developer/wiki/index.php?title=Pure_c%2b%2b_development) for more information.

One of the methods in the above link says:

> In ShiVa, create a game with one main AIModel that will act as a "proxy" between the engine and your C++ code, let's call it "AIProxy".
>
> In your "AIProxy", add for instance a handler named "onLoadScene", another one named "onMoveObject", etc.
>
> Import your objects, create your scenes, and any other assets you'll need at runtime.
>   Now, export your game as an STK file.
>
> On the Mac side, open the ShiVa Authoring Tool and create an Xcode project from your STK file.
>
> Now you can use the function "S3DClient_SendEventToCurrentUser" located in the "S3DClient_Wrapper.h" to call your "AIProxy" handlers from the C++ and/or Objective-C. For the opposite (calling the C++ from the Script you can use the hooks related functions).